# How I'll get the a grid panel's column width when the column is resized?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1

I use ExtJS 4.1 and I have no idea how to get grid panel's width when it is resized.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Why do you need to know column width?

Comment: @sha, I want to save it in the DB for later use.

Comment: There is standard mechanism to saving states for grid, panels and windows. I think you might redirect it to the DB as well. Did you check it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out `getState` method:
http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-getState

It's used by ExtJs to save/restore grid state including columns and their widths.